# How to rename a file downloaded by GoogleImageCrawler?

Tags: python

```
google_Crawler.crawl(keyword="person smiling", max_num=1)
```

How can I make this code save the file to a specific file name? I am using the icrawler package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works,

```
from icrawler import GoogleImageCrawler

class MyImageCrawler(GoogleImageCrawler):
    def file_path(self, task, response):
        return self.download_path + '/' + task['file_name']

google_Crawler = MyImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir': 'your_download_folder'})
google_Crawler.crawl(keyword='person smiling', max_num=1, file_name='my_image.jpg')
```